# How to access the parent class inside a resource

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, resources

I'm trying to create a complex tooltip, where one of the TextBlocks would be bound to a property of the UserControl in which this tooltip is defined as a resource. The simplified version of the XAML code looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.TestPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:pixellab="clr-namespace:PixelLab.Wpf;assembly=UIControls"
         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
         d:DesignHeight="499" d:DesignWidth="409"
         x:Name="PageInstance" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Key="Tooltip">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=PageInstance, Path=PageTest}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border Background="Red" ToolTip="{StaticResource Tooltip}" />
```

UserControl is named PageInstance. The border displayed inside has a tooltip defined as a resource. If I try to bind Text with

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=PageInstance, Path=PageTest}"/>
```

I get a binding error when I run the app:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : **Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=PageInstance'**. BindingExpression:Path=PageTest; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

What do I have to do to successfuly bind the text to the PageTest property in PageInstance usercontrol?

Thanks for any help. I still haven't completely figured out how Bindings work.
Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Border` will inherit the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`. Therefore modifying your tooltip as such...

```
<Grid x:Key="Tooltip">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTest}"/>
</Grid>
```

...and then setting the `DataContext` on your `UserControl` will push the model with the property `PageTest` down to your `Border` and subsequent children. This avoids the need to make use of `FindAncestor` in its entirety.

```
PageInstance.DataContext = model;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `RelativeSource` in your binding, something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=PageTest}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, the competition here is nothing compared to something like the C# tag though :P

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but unfortunately they don't work for me. I cannot use DataContext because in my real code I don't set this ToolTip on a Border but on a ListBoxItem and I need to use DataContext of that item (some items in tooltip are bound to that).. I set tooltip which already has a DataContext set that I need to use. Binding to the ancestor also didn't work for me since I still get the same error. Any other options?

Comment: That is weird, the RelativeSource binding should work in theory, other than that i can't think of anything else right now... (except setting the binding up in code-behind, if that would be an option?)

Comment: thanks. I totally forgot that I can set the binding in the code behind. This worked perfectly for me, thank you!